# Change Apple ID on iPhone without causing 'damage' to apps/app store purchases and keeping app data

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I have an old iPhone 5. It has lots of apps installed on it; there's a long message history in WhatsApp and other apps that I don't want to be deleted.

I have created a new Apple ID and want to use it on this iPhone.

How do I accomplish this without causing any damage to apps/app data? Also, if I change the ID, would I be able to update my apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the Apple ID on an iPhone. You can do this by going to Settings > iTunes and App Store and logout with your current Apple ID. After that, you can login with the new Apple ID.

When you download/purchase an app from the App Store, it will be connected to the Apple ID that is used to do the download/purchase. This means that if you start using a different Apple ID to download/purchase new apps, there's no problem to update them.

As you mentioned, you have for example WhatsApp installed. If there's an update for WhatsApp in the App Store, you are still able to update it, but you have to use the Apple ID password of your "old" Apple ID.

On a side note, you can make a backup from your WhatsApp history (texts and media) in iCloud. After this, you can delete and reinstall WhatsApp and restore the backup.

I don't know if other apps that are important for you have the same functionality to create a backup to iCloud.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful and well-explained. Specifically I just need Whatapp data and Message app (the default messaging app on iphone) data. For whatapp, I'll definitely use that backup feature that you mentioned. Could you also inform me as to how might I backup the messages data (iphone's default app) so that I can get my messages back on the new iphone with a new apple id?

Comment: Your data in the messages app wont be deleted

Answer (score -1):

I actually have apps on my computer that were purchased under two different Apple ID's, and the Mac simply asks me to enter the user-id and password that is associated with any app when it updates it.

Obviously, this id is "authorization to access a particular account on Apple's servers," not "authorization to run this app on your computer."

And, iPhones basically work the same way.